# In java string classes are final, than how did we enter value on string even its a final class?

Tags: java, strings, final

In Java string classes are final, we know that we can't inherit a final class and not able to write on this, then how did we enter a value on a string even its a final class?

Answer (score 6):

A `final` class cannot be inherited from.

Creating an instance of a class is not the same thing as inheriting from it. So you can do it, even though it's `final`.

Answer (score 2):

`String` is immutable, which means you can't modify it *once it has been created*. But of course you can choose how the string is created.

`String` has (as of Java 14) 16 constructors that all create string objects with values. You just call one of those.

In addition, there are 15 static methods on `String` that also create new strings, by calling some constructor (possibly a private one not included in the 16 above).

Comment: should probably add that the inheritence and the class being final is not strictly related to constructing values